# 8 996 498 07-52 / 07–52

Tags: орфография, пробелы, дефис-тире, цифры

Как писать правильно: с дефисом или средним тире? Думаю, нужен дефис, так как в WhatsApp'e, например, он таки используется.

`Мой номер — 8 996 498 07-52 / 07–52.`

Comment: Оч-чень хороший вопрос, ставлю плюс.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В «Справочнике издателя и автора» А. Мильчина и Л. Чельцовой:

> [**6.1.6. Номера телефонов**](https://img.artlebedev.ru/izdal/spravochnik-izdatelya-i-avtora/Milchin-Numbers.pdf)
> Их принято писать без знака номера, отделяя дефисом или пробелом по две цифры справа налево, исключая последнюю цифру, которую в семизначных номерах присоединяют к предыдущей группе цифр из двух знаков; напр.: *299-85-90, 299 85 90; 985-90, 985 90*. Телефонные номера с удачным сочетанием цифр (типа 222-3-222), оформляются так,
> как показано выше в скобках (дефисы при этом могут заменяться пробелами: 222 3 222)

Обычные городские номера: 123-45-67.
Номера с кодом города: (123) 123-45-67.
Номера мобильных телефонов: 8 123 123-45-67; +7 123 123-45-67.
Российские номера телефонов за рубежом: +7 123 123-45-67 либо (+7 123) 123-45-67.

Ваш номер: **8 996 498 07 52** (с пробелами), **8 996 498-07-52** (с дефисами).

Comment: Вы, вижу, хорошо разбираетесь в знаках препинания при цифрах. Именно вы потому что всегда отвечаете на вопросы о цифрах. Плюс ответу поставил.

Comment: Спасибо, Максим.