# Запись телефонного номера

Tags: дефис-тире, цифры

Скажите, пожалуйста, в номерах используется тире или дефис?
Например: **25-ФЗ** или **25—ФЗ**, **25-356** или **25—356**?

Comment: О какой фразе, каких номерах речь? Вопрос повиснет в воздухе, если не поясните.

Comment: Есть такая функция "принять ответ". Вы должны нажать на галочку рядом с ответом, который вам помог. Рекомендую это сделать с ответом ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Был недавно вопрос о телефонных номерах, поэтому ссылки приводить не стану.

[**8 996 498 07-52 / 07–52**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475810/8-996-498-07-52-07-52/475818#475818) (Как писать правильно: с дефисом или средним тире?)

При записи номеров нужно использовать **дефис**: ***25-ФЗ, 253-56.***

Каждой букве соответствует цифра. Цифры пишем отдельно, буквы — отдельно.
Если количество цифр и букв иное, чем в примере, то возможны такие варианты:
123-45-ЕЖ, 12-34-ЖАБА, 123-45-ГАД.

[...о дисковых телефонах](https://www.ufa.kp.ru/daily/26121/3014690/)